# Button not showing after coming back from Scale Animation

Tags: java, android, animation, button

I have a button which when you click it, a scale animation occurs on the button (scaling until 0), and then another screen shows up. when i hit back the button that i scaled does not show. Help?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, the "back" function programming is not appropriate. If you have used a back button, try programming the visibility of your scaled button in back button. Post your code for "back" function so that it will give a better idea of your need and your problem.